# Problem with showing preview in the admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, page-builder, magento2.4.4

We upgraded our webshop to Magento 2.4.4 from Magento 2.3.7-p1, but for now, we have to use PHP 7.4. After this, I saw that preview in the admin panel doesn't show components that we added before the upgrade.

Now it looks that:
[image]

Before the upgrade, it looked like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, I found the reason - it was due to that in a new version of Magento requires closing tags in HTML. Before we wrote code like that: `<span repeat="8"/>`, but now we have to write in this way: `<span repeat="8"></span>`